# how to cuztomize confirm box ,or make our own conform box

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have tried to apply css rules for that conformation box but i did not get the expected resutl.
i want a conformation when user click on an item to delete.
here is html

```
<div class="myitem">
   <a href="example.php/one">Delete Item one</a>
   <a href="example.php/two">Delete Item two</a>
   <a href="example.php/three">Delete Item three</a>
   <a href="example.php/four">Delete Item four</a>
   </div>

   javascript here
   $('.myitem a').click(
    function(){ confirm("Are Your Sure?");}
   )
```

Comment: given is js fiddle link"
http://jsfiddle.net/b9s75uhd/2/

Comment: Hi James Donnelly , i already have seen that question but not saticified answer and i dont want to use any plugin for that , i want any small jquery function if it is not possibel by css

Comment: Please don't mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you're going to be able to do this is to move away from confirmation boxes altogether in favour of model dialogs. Plenty of these are available after a quick google search. (jQueryUI, Bootstrap, etc).